# Bundle install fails on mysql gem in scaled OpenShift Online application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, openshift

I can't seem to figure out how to fix this bundle install error (on a mysql gem) that I'm getting when I do a git push to OpenShift Online. When it gets to the mysql gem, I get an error "cannot find -lmysqlclient" when it's doing a make (see below).

I've created a simple (from the quickstart), **scaled** Rails 4 app on OpenShift Online with MySQL5.5. I have RAILS_ENV set to "development" and am forcing a clean build.

I'm getting an error on *bundle install* when it gets to the mysql gem that only occurs when the application is **scaled** and RAILS_ENV = 'development'.

When I create the same app as unscaled (Rails 4 with MySQL 5.5) and setting RAILS_ENV = 'development', it works fine. But I have to use a "scaled" app to expose a DB HOST that my Iron.io worker can connect with to lookup users and other info.

NOTE: it works fine when RAILS_ENV = 'production', but I'm going to have multiple environment-specific versions of the app (e.g. app-dev, app-stg, app) running on OpenShift Online, which is why I need to have RAILS_ENV set to 'development'.

I have a force_clean_build marker under .openshift/markers.

This is the code I have in .openshift/action_hooks/pre_build:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is a simple script and will be executed on your CI system if
# available.  Otherwise it will execute while your application is stopped
# before the build step.  This script gets executed directly, so it
# could be python, php, ruby, etc.

if [[ "$RUBY_VERSION" == "1.8" ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: This quickstart is not compatible with Ruby 1.8"
  echo "ERROR: Please use ruby-1.9 or ruby-2.0 application type."
  exit 1
fi

source $OPENSHIFT_CARTRIDGE_SDK_BASH
source ${OPENSHIFT_RUBY_DIR}/lib/ruby_context

set -e

pushd ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR} > /dev/null

if [[ -f .openshift/markers/force_clean_build && ( "$RAILS_ENV" == "development" || "$RAILS_ENV" == "staging" ) ]]
then
  echo "bundle install --deployment --path ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}app-root/repo/vendor/bundle"
  ruby_with_nodejs_context "bundle install --deployment --path ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}app-root/repo/vendor/bundle"
fi

popd > /dev/null
```

The is a log of what happens when I do a 'git push':

```
remote: Ruby cartridge in development mode, skipping stop...
remote: Repairing links for 1 deployments
remote: Syncing git content to other proxy gears
remote: Force clean build enabled - cleaning dependencies
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit bc3ac62
remote: bundle install --deployment --path /var/lib/openshift/548b3d09fcf933241c0001b6/app-root/repo/vendor/bundle
remote: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote: Installing rake (0.9.6) 
remote: Installing i18n (0.6.11) 
remote: Installing json (1.8.1) 
remote: Installing minitest (5.4.3) 
remote: Installing thread_safe (0.3.4) 
remote: Installing tzinfo (1.2.2) 
remote: Installing activesupport (4.1.4) 
remote: Installing builder (3.2.2) 
remote: Installing erubis (2.7.0) 
remote: Installing actionview (4.1.4) 
remote: Installing rack (1.5.2) 
remote: Installing rack-test (0.6.2) 
remote: Installing actionpack (4.1.4) 
remote: Installing mime-types (1.25.1) 
remote: Installing polyglot (0.3.5) 
remote: Installing treetop (1.4.15) 
remote: Installing mail (2.5.4) 
remote: Installing actionmailer (4.1.4) 
remote: Installing activemodel (4.1.4) 
remote: Installing arel (5.0.1.20140414130214) 
remote: Installing activerecord (4.1.4) 
remote: Installing coffee-script-source (1.8.0) 
remote: Installing execjs (2.2.2) 
remote: Installing coffee-script (2.3.0) 
remote: Installing thor (0.19.1) 
remote: Installing railties (4.1.4) 
remote: Installing coffee-rails (4.0.1) 
remote: Installing hike (1.2.3) 
remote: Installing multi_json (1.10.1) 
remote: Installing jbuilder (2.2.5) 
remote: Installing jquery-rails (3.1.2) 
remote: Installing mysql2 (0.3.17) 
remote: Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote: 
remote:     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
remote: checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
remote: checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
remote: checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
remote: checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
remote: checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
remote: checking for rb_intern3()... yes
remote: -----
remote: Using mysql_config at /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/mysql_config
remote: -----
remote: checking for mysql.h... yes
remote: checking for errmsg.h... yes
remote: checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
remote: -----
remote: Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
remote: -----
remote: -----
remote: Setting libpath to /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64/mysql
remote: -----
remote: creating Makefile
remote: 
remote: make "DESTDIR="
remote: gcc -I. -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I. -I/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql -DHAVE_RUBY_THREAD_H -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CALL_WITHOUT_GVL -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_WAIT_FOR_SINGLE_FD -DHAVE_RB_HASH_DUP -DHAVE_RB_INTERN3 -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mtune=generic -fPIC -m64 -o client.o -c client.c
remote: gcc -I. -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I. -I/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql -DHAVE_RUBY_THREAD_H -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CALL_WITHOUT_GVL -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_WAIT_FOR_SINGLE_FD -DHAVE_RB_HASH_DUP -DHAVE_RB_INTERN3 -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mtune=generic -fPIC -m64 -o infile.o -c infile.c
remote: gcc -I. -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I. -I/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql -DHAVE_RUBY_THREAD_H -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CALL_WITHOUT_GVL -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_WAIT_FOR_SINGLE_FD -DHAVE_RB_HASH_DUP -DHAVE_RB_INTERN3 -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mtune=generic -fPIC -m64 -o mysql2_ext.o -c mysql2_ext.c
remote: gcc -I. -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I. -I/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql -DHAVE_RUBY_THREAD_H -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CALL_WITHOUT_GVL -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_WAIT_FOR_SINGLE_FD -DHAVE_RB_HASH_DUP -DHAVE_RB_INTERN3 -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mtune=generic -fPIC -m64 -o result.o -c result.c
remote: rm -f mysql2.so
remote: gcc -shared -o mysql2.so client.o infile.o mysql2_ext.o result.o -L. -L/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/lib64 -L/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64/mysql -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -m64  -lruby -L/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
remote: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
remote: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
remote: make: *** [mysql2.so] Error 1
remote: 
remote: 
remote: Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/openshift/548b3d09fcf933241c0001b6/app-root/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/mysql2-0.3.17 for inspection.
remote: Results logged to /var/lib/openshift/548b3d09fcf933241c0001b6/app-root/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
remote: An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.17), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote: Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'` succeeds before bundling.
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 5)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute action hook 'pre_build' for 548b3d09fcf933241c0001b6 application rorscaled
remote: 
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
To ssh://548b3d09fcf933241c0001b6@rorscaled-pervasivio.rhcloud.com/~/git/rorscaled.git/
   3d4699e..bc3ac62  master -> master
```

OpenShift Online MYSQL environment variables for this scaled app, and the same unscaled version of the app.

```
SCALED -----

OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_GEAR_DNS=548b3d09fcf933241c0001b7-pervasivio.rhcloud.com
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_GEAR_UUID=548b3d09fcf933241c0001b7
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=548b3d09fcf933241c0001b7-pervasivio.rhcloud.com
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT=37891
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL=mysql://adminHucinW7:yVMbdWxil46k@548b3d09fcf933241c0001b7-pervasivio.rhcloud.com:37891/
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ELEMENT=/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_PATH_ELEMENT=/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin

UNSCALED -----

OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=127.4.220.2
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_LOG_DIR=/var/lib/openshift/548b2e04e0b8cd0f2800005a/app-root/logs/
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT=3306
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_SOCKET=/var/lib/openshift/548b2e04e0b8cd0f2800005a/mysql//socket/mysql.sock
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL=mysql://adminbZ743Ky:PnvGtW7CfScB@127.4.220.2:3306/
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DIR=/var/lib/openshift/548b2e04e0b8cd0f2800005a/mysql/
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_IDENT=redhat:mysql:5.5:0.2.19
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ELEMENT=/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_VERSION=5.5
```

Comment: What cartridges are you using?  And are you using rhc port-forward on your iron.io worker?  Otherwise how would your worker talk to the database?  That FQDN of the db gear is not world accessible...

Comment: I'm using the Ruby 2.0 and MySQL 5.5 cartridges. I haven't gotten to the point of connecting with my iron.io worker yet because of this error. I read that you have to have a paid account with a scaled app in order to be able to connect to MySQL from outside the app. Unscaled the DB HOST is 127.4.68.2 (or something like that). I'm able to use rhc port-forward to connect from my local dev environment. I'll post a listing of the MYSQL OpenShift environment variables for both my scaled and unscaled apps, so you can see the difference in DB HOST and other values.

Comment: I'm afraid I gave too much information above :-(. I just wanted to be thorough, but the real issue is the bundle install error on the mysql gem (for a scaled app) ONLY when RAILS_ENV=development. When RAILS_ENV=production, there's no problem with the bundle install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I went back to using a MySQL 5.1 OpenShift cartridge and the error was resolved.